# XGBoost objective function for regression where I am most concerned about predicting bottom decile

Tags: python, regression, xgboost

I have gotten decent results using the default regression objective function with XGBoost and a random forest with early stopping.

My goal is to be able to predict the bottom decile of my data well, and I am wondering if there is an objective function that will allow me to do this? I am less concerned about the other deciles, so long as I can predict the bottom well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could define a categorical variable, equal to 0 in the bottom decile and 1 otherwise, and then use  `XGBClassifier.` This has the potential of working better (I have had some success with classifiers in regression problems).

Comment: I tried that but the problem was that distance between actual answer and predicted answer wasn't taken into account - the model ended up predicting lots in the bottom decile correctly, but also many extremely wrong answers (predicting a bottom decile that was actually top decile). Hence regression, where distance from actual vs. prediction is taken into account in objective.

Comment: @xxanissrxx Well, you can do a multiclass classification: 1 for bottom decile, say, 0 for second from the bottom and -1 for the rest.

Comment: The same problem happens. All of the mistakes are the extreme opposite, and from the very top decile.

Comment: @xxanissrxx I assume this was NOT happening with regression. Or was it?

Comment: No not happening with regression.

Comment: @xxanissrxx Very curious. This must be due to some idiosyncrasy of your data set.